# Access image from cloud storage given the name inside of a model in Django-Python

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I am in need of ideas/help. I am saving the image from my angular client into a cloud storage bucket and saving the name of the file in a django model in mysql.

I am able to access the file if I create an url like the one below on a django template:

```
{% for visitor in visitors%}

<img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/BUCKET_NAME/{{visitor.image_name}}">

{% endfor %}
```

This works because I have added my organization to have permissions in the cloud bucket, so when I am signed in onto Gmail, it will let me output the picture. But once I am signed out, it will not output the picture. And since; this works on a Desktop computer for me, but not on a mobile device.

What is another way I can access this picture from my cloud bucket? given my current model. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose from the link structure that you are using "Authenticated URL" instead of "Public URL". If you take a look on file in Google Cloud Storage [browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) and if it's access is set to "Public to internet" you can find there 2 urls, in my test project it is:

**Public URL:** `https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket-name]/original.jpg`

**Authenticated URL:** `https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucket-name]/original.jpg`,

I suppose that this looks similarly on your side. So to access to to the file without authentication you have to use public link. Looking at sample code provided at the moment this seems to be authenticated url.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! The reason I had not used the public URL or made the images in the bucket public is because these pictures are private and cannot be made available for the entire web. Thanks a lot for your response though!